# Redirect all https to http, except 3 pages [htaccess / php]

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

Running a wordpress site, therefore it already has its own rule to remove index.php from links. Furthermore, every time in a url there is "cache_img", a specific rule applies.

What I need:

1. **for the current rules to keep working**
2. **in case a url is in https, rewrite it with http (301), EXCEPT 3 pages (bookingstep1, bookingstep2, bookingsep3)**

I suck at htaccess, it makes little to no sense to me, I hope someone can help me with this. I'm open to either htaccess or php solutions.

This is what I have at the moment (and it may already have mistakes in it...)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(cache_img) [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^cache_img/(.*)x(.*)-(.*)/r/(.*) cache_img/tt.php?src=http://mydomain.com/$4&w=$1&h=$2&zc=$3&q=100
```

I tried with adding at the top of my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !^bookingstep(1|2|3)\/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which works for all pages... it removes the https and rewrites them with http.
But it also rewrite the bookinstep* pages :(

Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this plugin a go:

> http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https

I personally use it all of the time. You can make every page https or can go into individual pages/posts and just make those individually secure.

> EDIT

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^bookingstep1/?$ https://URL HERE/bookingstep1[R=301,QSA,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^bookingstep2/?$ https://URL HERE/bookingstep2[R=301,QSA,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^bookingstep3/?$ https://URL HERE/bookingstep3[R=301,QSA,L,NE]
```

Comment: I would like to avoid using plugins for this.
The problem is not getting the SSL pages I need to work, the problem is that once you are in HTTPS, and browse to another internal page, that too will be in HTTPS automatically then... and that's exactly what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect all `https` to `http`

Code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

For More Details see [here](http://prittytimes.com/wordpress-redirect-https-to-http-with-htaccess/)

Comment: I had to exclude specific pages, so this isnt a solution unfortunately.